# af::array conversion to float or double

Tags: rcpp, arrayfire

I have been experimenting with the RcppArrayFire Package, mostly rewriting some cost functions from RcppArmadillo and can't seem to get over "no viable conversion from 'af::array' to 'float'.  I have also been getting some backend errors, the example below seems free of these.

This cov-var example is written poorly just to use all relevant coding pieces from my actual cost function.  As of now it is the only addition in a package generated by, "RcppArrayFire.package.skeleton".

```cpp
#include "RcppArrayFire.h"
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArrayFire)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
float example_ols(const RcppArrayFire::typed_array<f32>& X_vect,  const RcppArrayFire::typed_array<f32>& Y_vect){

  int Len = X_vect.dims()[0];
  int Len_Y = Y_vect.dims()[0];

  while( Len_Y < Len){
    Len --;
  }

  float mean_X = af::sum(X_vect)/Len;
  float mean_Y = af::sum(Y_vect)/Len;

  RcppArrayFire::typed_array<f32> temp(Len);
  RcppArrayFire::typed_array<f32> temp_x(Len);

  for( int f = 0; f < Len; f++){
    temp(f) = (X_vect(f) - mean_X)*(Y_vect(f) - mean_Y);
    temp_x(f) = af::pow(X_vect(f) -mean_X, 2);
  }

  return af::sum(temp)/af::sum(temp_x);
}


/*** R
  X <- 1:10
  Y <- 2*X +rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  example_ols(X, Y)
*/
```

Comment: You are aware that R has no 32-bit floating value aka `float`, right?

Comment: No I wasn't, irrespective I don't think my GPU will handle a double precision and I mentioned I had the same error converting from af::array to a double

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to consider is the [`af::sum`](http://arrayfire.org/docs/group__reduce__func__sum.htm) function, which comes in different forms: An `sf::sum(af::array)` that returns an `af::array` in device memory and a templated `af::sum<T>(af::array)` that returns a `T` in host memory. So the minimal change to your example would be using `af::sum<float>`:

```cpp
#include "RcppArrayFire.h"
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArrayFire)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
float example_ols(const RcppArrayFire::typed_array<f32>& X_vect,
                  const RcppArrayFire::typed_array<f32>& Y_vect){

    int Len = X_vect.dims()[0];
    int Len_Y = Y_vect.dims()[0];

    while( Len_Y < Len){
        Len --;
    }

    float mean_X = af::sum<float>(X_vect)/Len;
    float mean_Y = af::sum<float>(Y_vect)/Len;

    RcppArrayFire::typed_array<f32> temp(Len);
    RcppArrayFire::typed_array<f32> temp_x(Len);

    for( int f = 0; f < Len; f++){
        temp(f) = (X_vect(f) - mean_X)*(Y_vect(f) - mean_Y);
        temp_x(f) = af::pow(X_vect(f) -mean_X, 2);
    }

    return af::sum<float>(temp)/af::sum<float>(temp_x);
}


/*** R
set.seed(1)
X <- 1:10
Y <- 2*X +rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1)
example_ols(X, Y)
*/
```

However, there are more things one can improve. In no particular order:

- You don't need to include `Rcpp.h`.
- There is an `af::mean` function for computing the mean of an `af::array`.
- In general `RcppArrayFire::typed_array<T>` is only needed for getting arrays from R into C++. Within C++ and for the way back you can use `af::array`.
- Even when your device does not support `double`, you can still use `double` values on the host.
- In order to get good performance, you should avoid `for` loops and use [vectorized functions](http://arrayfire.org/docs/vectorization.htm), just like in R. You have to impose equal dimensions for `X` and `Y`, though.

Interestingly I get a different result when I use vectorized functions. Right now I am not sure why this is the case, but the following form makes more sense to me. You should verify that the result is what you want to get:

```cpp
#include <RcppArrayFire.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArrayFire)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double example_ols(const RcppArrayFire::typed_array<f32>& X_vect,
                   const RcppArrayFire::typed_array<f32>& Y_vect){

    double mean_X = af::mean<double>(X_vect);
    double mean_Y = af::mean<double>(Y_vect);

    af::array temp = (X_vect - mean_X) * (Y_vect - mean_Y);
    af::array temp_x = af::pow(X_vect - mean_X, 2.0);

    return af::sum<double>(temp)/af::sum<double>(temp_x);
}

/*** R
set.seed(1)
X <- 1:10
Y <- 2*X +rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1)
example_ols(X, Y)
*/
```

BTW, an even shorter version would be:

```cpp
#include <RcppArrayFire.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArrayFire)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
af::array example_ols(const RcppArrayFire::typed_array<f32>& X_vect,
                      const RcppArrayFire::typed_array<f32>& Y_vect){

    return af::cov(X_vect, Y_vect) / af::var(X_vect);
}
```

Generally it is a good idea to use the in-build functions as much as possible.

Comment: I will add this bit incase anyone else has the same problem.  Not necessarily needed for this example but useful.  To extract an element from an af::array *array_name(index_number).host<type>() i.e. in this example something like *X_vect(0).host<double>() . This is needed for stuff like logical comparisons